# Odoo13 QWEB report pdf name

Tags: odoo-10, odoo-11, odoo-12, odoo-13, qweb

On my custom modules that generate pdf reports the field "print_report_name" not name the report. I need report name + datetime actual.
Always take the name of the "name" field from the report definition.

I used it with Odoo10CE and it works perfectly.
Maybe there is another way to do it from the v10? I found nothing in the documentation.

Comment: Which version are you using Odoo10 CE?

Comment: The problem occurs with Odoo 13 CE

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this tag for your custom report name print under report tag. Right now I am using basic module. You can use your custom field and model for your use.

```
<field name="print_report_name">'%s - %s' % (object.name, object.date_done)</field>
```

Block of code for your reference.

```
   <record id="action_report_lot_label" model="ir.actions.report">
        <field name="name">Lot/Serial Number (PDF)</field>
        <field name="model">stock.production.lot</field>
        <field name="report_type">qweb-pdf</field>
        <field name="report_name">stock.report_lot_label</field>
        <field name="report_file">stock.report_lot_label</field>
        <field name="print_report_name">'%s - %s' % (object.name, object.date_done)</field>
        <field name="binding_model_id" ref="model_stock_production_lot"/>
        <field name="binding_type">report</field>
    </record>
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work on my system with Odoo13CE. Always take the name of the Name field from the report definition. Tested with the "My Report" module.